# How to implement the Visitor pattern for subtypes of an abstract class or interface?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, visitor-pattern

I'm having this specific issue I couldn't sort out with other questions.
I'm trying to implement a Visitor for a game, the visitor is an `Attack` class and it has to search in a matrix for cells that may contain `Characters`, then if the character is an enemy and not a friend, damage it.

What I'm having trouble is not using an `InstanceOf` to visit the character, as it breaks the Open-Closed Principle.
Here's my code:

*Visitor interface*

```
public interface Visitor {
    public void visit(GroundCell c);
    public void visit(MountainCell c);
    public void visit(BuildingCell c);
    public void visit(WaterCell c);
    public void visit(Foe f);
    public void visit(Friend f);}
```

*Attack abstract class*

```
public abstract class Attack implements Visitor {

}
```

*Attack concrete class*

```
public class TankAttack extends Attack{

...

@Override
public void visit(GroundCell c) {
    //here, i'd like to call  c.getCharacter.accept(this) 
}
```

But I get an error that says *I should first implement Visit(Character c)*, when I need it only for its subclasses.

What should I do in the TankAttack class to visit the Friend or Foe subclasses of Character and not break the design using InstanceOf?

Edit for clarification: Friend and Foe are subclasses of Character.

Answer (score 0):

The visitor doesn't work in this way.

All classes declared as parameter here are visited classes :

```
public void visit(GroundCell c);
public void visit(MountainCell c);
public void visit(BuildingCell c);
public void visit(WaterCell c);
public void visit(Foe f);
public void visit(Friend f);}
```

All of these have to define an `accept(Visitor visitor)` method that means "I accept to be visited by a visitor".
Inside of them we invoke : `visitor.visit(this)` to perform effectively the visit with the expected overload (double dispatch).

In this way you can write :

```
Attack attack = new TankAttack(); // visitor
Visited visitedOne = new GroundCell(); // visited one
Visited visitedTwo = new MountainCell(); // visited two

// accept the visitor and perform the double dispatch to invoke the specific method
visitedOne.accept(attack); 
visitedTwo.accept(attack);
```

Or more generally you expose a method with the base type of visitor as parameter such as :

```
public void attack(Visited visited, Attack attack){
     visited.accept(attack); // no need instance of
}
```

And use it :

```
attack(new GroundCell(), attack); 
attack(new MoutainCell(), attack);
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with genericity here, I believe. What's wrong is not my Visited classes but the fact I want to visit the subclasses of the class a method returns. I get a Character from Groundcell.getCharacter() and I need to visit that, which may be a Friend or a Foe. The compiler asks me to implement an Accept(Visitor v) method in Character, when I don't really need it there.

Comment: As in your visit() body you want to invoke accept() (while that is the reverse) , I think that you didn't grasp the overall idea of the pattern. Why don't you think that Character (that is seemingly the visited class) don't need to define an accept() method. That is the way which the patterns works.

Comment: So, if Characters implement accept, when I visit the returned character, It will call Character.accept() and not the one on the subclass I need (friend.accept() or foe.accept()) that will have different behavior. That’s my problem. I need to be able to discern what instance the character will be so I can call its specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after hours. This problem was not caused by an erroneous implementation of the Visitor pattern, but because the superclass is called `Character`, just as `java.lang.Character`. Be wary of not overwriting this class when programming a java game.